# I can't access cookie returned after http post in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cookies, node-request

I have a simple NodeJS app which authenticates with remote Java CMS. On successful authentication the CMS returns a cookie.

However, for the life of me I can't figure how to access / get this cookie value. (I need the cookie in order to make requests to the CMS's API, once authenticated).

I get the cookie returned in a curl command ok but can't access it in NodeJS.
Curl Command:

```
curl -v -k --data "username=admin&password=password111&realm=cms101"     
    https://test.abeo.ie/gatekeeper/rs/authenticate/login
```

Now here is my NodeJS app's code:

```
    //disable self-signed ssl cert rejection
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

    var http = require('http');
    var request = require('request');
    var Cookies = require('cookies');

    //enable cookies
    request.defaults({jar: true});


    request({
        url: 'https://test.abeo.ie/gatekeeper/rs/authenticate/login', //URL to hit
        qs: {username: 'admin', password: 'password111', realm: 'cms101'}, //Query string data
        method: 'POST', //Specify the method
        headers: { //We can define headers too
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }


    },

    function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {

             //response.cookie comes out as 'undefined'
            console.log(response.statusCode, body, response.cookie);

        }
    })
```

So my question is: How do I read the cookie value from the response as the response.cookie value prints out as undefined.

Thanks,

Mike

** If this question seems to vague... Just say so and I will clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have just answered my question :)

I had the syntax wrong and instead of

```
 console.log(response.statusCode, body, response.cookie);
```

I needed

```
console.log(response.statusCode, body, response.headers['set-cookie']);
```

Just working on parsing the thing now :)